# Adding data into dataframe using row and column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to add data into a dataframe using the row and column values, something like this:

```
random = len(list(df.columns))//2
append_str = "Column-"
test_list = range(1,random+1)
test_list = [str(x) for x in test_list]
Columns = [append_str + sub for sub in test_list]
#op_df should have exactly half the length as that of df
op_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=Columns)
for row in rows:
    for col in cols:
       op_df[f"Column-{col+1}"][row] = df[f"Column-{2*col+1}"][row]
print(op_df)
```

The above code throws me this error:

KeyError: 0
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

**Please note that the lists "rows" and "cols" aren't sorted.**

Let me know the fix for it if any or please let me know the alternative way of doing this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would build up a python data structure and then create the DataFrame. The easiest way to do this is with a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a list of lists to solve this. Finally, I converted this list of lists into dataframe.